Using transfer via in PCB
From which frequency we need to consider a transfer via, when there is a transition of a signal on different layer in a PCB? higher than 1GHz? I need to know the threshold for considering these types of vias?

Reference of the picture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPT96w3eLAM

This graph from Le Leivre.com is a pretty good indicator of inductance: -

So, a via with a 0.6 mm diameter hole on a PCB substrate that is 0.75 mm thick has an inductance of 100 pH: -

Then, there's this Via inductance calculator that may be more useful for transfer vias: -

It's still pretty much come up with the same result of the previous graph for a regular via. So, take your pick.
At 1 GHz that's an inductive reactance of 0.628 Ω and probably not too much of a worry for regular data transmission applications at (say) up to 200 Mbps using a characteristic impedance of 50 Ω.

From which frequency we need to consider a transfer via, when there is
a transition of a signal on different layer in a PCB? higher than
1GHz? I need to know the threshold for considering these types of
vias?

It's down to the application i.e. there is no threshold other than what your application can tolerate. Simulation is also part of the answer. Simulation will help you determine at what point the via inductance becomes problematic.

I don't think the OP is talking about the inductance of the signal via, it's the necessity for the ground 'transfer via' he's on about, which of course doesn't transfer anything in his illustration.

@ Andy aka would you please let me know by which software should I do the simulation?

I use microcap 12 for circuit simulation. The link opens up the zip file should you want to download it. Other folk use LTspice but many of us use microcap because it is now free and has full libraries compared to LTspice @Andromeda

Phil has talked about transfer vias, and then illustrated one that isn't (above).
In the short section in the video on transfer vias, he shows you vias in a 6 layer board. It probably has multiple ground planes, and those ground vias are to stitch the ground planes together, and especially where a signal moves from a layer referencing one ground plane to a layer referencing a different plane, to ensure ground current continuity between the two reference planes. It's vitally important to get ground plane continuity at frequencies waaaay less than 1 GHz. This applies to where the ground that the signal reference changes plane, and also where a single ground plane is broken by a 'last minute' track that has to be routed, cutting the ground plane.
In your illustration, there is only one ground plane. The two signal layers each reference the same plane. Ground return current flows quite happily round the edge of the ground plane beside the signal via.
The 'transfer' via that is shown in your illustration is only connected to one ground plane, it's not transferring anything. The only thing it might be doing for signal integrity if changing the capacitance to ground by virtue of its proximity. That's not really necessary at 1 GHz.
To directly answer your question about frequencies. If you have multiple ground planes, they should be stitched together by vias, on boards of almost any frequency. The vias should be closer to any signal tracks that change ground reference than λ/20 at the highest operating frequency (closer is better), and in general closer to each other than λ/10.
In the specific case you have illustrated in your question, the ground via is doing nothing for current flow, but merely affecting the electrostatic field around the signal via. This might be important for track matching at many GHz, where you would have to design it properly, but it's not needed at 1 GHz.
